# Query to write latest changed customer id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query, hierarchical-query

Тhe customer `id` get updated regularly. There is a table
that records this change.

```
Customer id, Customer’s Previous id, Customer’s Successor id
100,95,102
101,96,105
102,100,104
103,99,106
107,88,111
```

We need from this data for each customer `id`, that latest changed customer `id`. A sample of that from
above data would be:

```
Customer id, Latest Customer id
100,104
101,105
102,104
103,106
107,111
```

Comment: Please show what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: you could create a table where you store the latest customer id with the last updated date

Comment: If you have any date column on table which gets updated. Just use order by date.

Comment: no date column is there . only three columns are there

Comment: That's a question from one of our coding interview rounds :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `LEFT JOIN` if `ID` is updated only once

```
SELECT A.CID,COALESCE(B.SCID,A.SCID) AS LCID
FROM #TABLEA A LEFT JOIN #TABLEA B ON A.CID=B.PCID
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=99ba0669e5829ee7aed86f9d65cfffd1)

Output

```
+---------------+-------------------+
| Customer ID   | Latest Customer id|
+---------------+-------------------+
| 100           | 104               |
| 101           | 105               |
| 102           | 104               |
| 103           | 106               |
| 107           | 111               |
+---------------+-------------------+
```

*Note: Here I have refereed  Customer ID  as CID, Previous Customer ID as PCID & Successor Customer ID  as SCID*

Comment: @PushpakKumar . . . This may work for your sample data but it is not going to work if there are multiple changes over time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , Yes that's true. I was under impression that it will be updated once for each ID. now i have added the note. Thanks for pointing out !

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it with a recursive cte:

```
with cte(customer_id, next_customer_id, lvl) as (
    select customer_id, next_customer_id, 0
    from mytable t
    where not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.customer_id = t.prev_customer_id)
    union all
    select c.customer_id, t.next_customer_id, lvl + 1
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.customer_id = c.next_customer_id
)
select * 
from cte c
where lvl = (select max(c1.lvl) from cte c1 where c1.customer_id = c.customer_id)
order by customer_id
```

The anchor of the CTE selects the records for which no "previous" record exists; then, the recursive members walks the relationship towards the "next" records. Finally, the outer query filters on the "last" value per customer.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9469f3de979690d70f81f80254c437a9)**:

```
customer_id | next_customer_id | lvl
----------: | ---------------: | --:
        100 |              104 |   1
        101 |              105 |   0
        103 |              106 |   0
        107 |              111 |   0
```

Note that tuple `(102,104)` is not showing in the resultset, because it actually belongs to the hierarchy of customer `100`, whose path is `100 > 102 > 104`.

Comment: @pushpakKumar . . . A recursive CTE is the general solution to this problem.